# Google Results Remove old website

Tags: google-search, google-search-console

I recently deployed a new website for my client that used some PHP framework I don't know of. The URL always included /index.php/ in all the requests so that the framework problably handles the index.php as some kind of front controller.

The website has been replaced for almost 3 months but I still see lots of old results like this in Google's Search Console.

```
/index.php/moveable-asset-auctions/furniture.html
/index.php/auctions.php?atype=5
```

When I open these links a broken page is displayed and this is probably why they don't dissapear from Google's results, because the page still opens.
I tried .htaccess to redirect all traffic but couldn't find a solution.
Lastly I added these lines to my index.php to force a redirect for anything under /index.php/

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],"index.php/")) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    header("Location: http://www.website.com/");
}
```

1.) My question is, is this the correct way of handling this? and...

2.) How do I remove the old Analytic and Google search stats? (It's messing with the results and still appears on searches)

**Edit:** I Have submitted a Remove URL request through the console, so will see what happens in the next few days (But only of the top level /index.php/ directory, so hopefully it will recurse through all the sub-links and pages)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for your case is to redirect all the links using 301 redirect, this will make the page rank flow from the old pages to the new ones and redirect the users if they come from search results pages.

If you don't have new pages equally to the old ones, its ok to redirect them (301) to the homepage and after 2 or 3 weeks you will see the errors disappear from google webmaster.